# Is growth in Python questions now spurting?

Tags: discussion, questions, statistics, unanswered-questions

I've been looking at a few metrics lately to see how the site is running. Instead of new sign-up's, flags and voting, a more balanced metric in my view 'are questions being answered'.

Remember there are under 1 million users who [actively answer](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow).

So I put together [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/1267573#graph) ([based on Rene's excellent answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312499/156316)) and there's one outlier, Python:

[image]

I know the reasons for Python's popularity in recent years, but can anyone explain this sudden boost?

Comment: wonder if you checked how it matches the dates of impact of [meta-tag:automatic-deletion]. Because the surge at one year back from now suspiciously looks like 365-days roomba script

Comment: It seems Python is on an upwards trend in general but @gnat is correct - this might not be accounting for the deleted questions.

Comment: Apparently it's too early for me to try and work with SQL. I tried to add the PostsWithDeleted table to the query but I somehow keep failing. My intent was to do a union over Posts and PostsWithDeleted to maybe get a better result.

Comment: @VLAZ PostWithDeleted is the table the Posts view is based on. You won't see any difference because the PostTags table doesn't have the records for deleted posts. If you want that you need to split the Tags field in the PostsWithDeleted because that is not nullified for deleted posts

Comment: @rene that explains why I was getting the same results...

Comment: That query looked familiar: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312499/158100 the comments in that code gave it away ...

Comment: Somehow related that the recent question quality is abysmal, generally speaking? No effort at all, low effort, missing error messages, screenshots of code: it's all there.

Comment: @usr2564301 that's the case site-wide, as far as I'm aware. Python being a popular tag just sees more of it because there are more questions submitted. I think there is also some skewing where more popular tags also get *proportionally* more bad questions but again - popularity is mostly to blame.

Comment: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=python%2Cjavascript%2Cjava

Comment: Also, more high schools are teaching Python now, rather than (say) Java.

Comment: @Rene - kudo's attached, apologies it wasn't meant as plagiarism. I'll also update the SEDE..

Comment: @VLAZ here is the graph for just [Python](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1268248#graph) separated in deleted/not deleted.

Comment: @Hans knows [what I want](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27109/1056), specifying the Y-Axis ScaleUnits to 16% reveals Python's meteoric rise without the spurt. Something fishy going on with the Unanswered Python that could have skewed the results. I need the advice the site running higher quantities of questions now with covid.

Comment: The x-axis is guessable, but [what is (the unit) on the y-axis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pPJf8KrvJXU&t=10m54s)? Questions per week? Per month?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think it's "Questions per month", as there are 12 dots in a year.

Comment: I wanted to run the query again including newer data but it gave an execution timeout. Any instructions on how to run the query?

Comment: @Trilarion - I'm not sure how to optimise the query without sacrificing data points, sadly I get the same error **Line 0: Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.**

Comment: Maybe just calculate only for the last say four years. The older data points are already there and not much will have changed (some old questions could be deleted in the mean time). If I have time I can tinker around with it.